# ReactNative build for android just freezes over the last step

Tags: android, react-native, compilation

I was developing a React Native project as always; when I encountered the following error after doing `react-native run android` or equivalently `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug`.
It's just over the last step that this exception is caught:`

```
:app:assembleDebug
:app:installDebug
Exception in thread "Device List Monitor" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.checkConnection(EmulatorConsole.java:317)
        at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.getConsole(EmulatorConsole.java:231)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.queryAvdName(DeviceMonitor.java:248)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.updateDevices(DeviceMonitor.java:220)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$400(DeviceMonitor.java:65)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListUpdateListener.deviceListUpdate(DeviceMonitor.java:662)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListMonitorTask.processIncomingDeviceData(DeviceMonitor.java:847)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListMonitorTask.run(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Building 97% > :app:installDebug`
```

I'm coding on react-native version 0.43.2 and react-native-cli 2.0.1, also npm 4.1.2 and yarn 0.21.3; Ubuntu 16.04. So everything is armed to teeth by the latest version but I still can't figure out the problem. It happens even for a project I just create by `react-native init`, it's every where. :(
P.S. be sure my emulator is up and running and the problem isn't due to it.

Comment: I had this exact error when accessing the second emulator instance "emulator-5556". Turns out, I had a Chrome WebExtension that had an open port overlapping 5556 which is also used by the emulator. If this is the first emulator instance, it would have been 5554 so check for other programs using that set of ports with `netstat -ltpn` or whatever is appropriate for your OS.

Answer (score 18):

Try restarting adb in to make it probe the local 5554 port

```
killall adb; adb devices
```

Comment: In my case I also had to kill the Android emulator, which was a process called "qemu-system-x86_64"

Comment: @this.lau_ if you kill Android emulator how do you intend to run you all? You have no devices connected...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I never found the reason or the solution to the problem. But what I know, I went on with my daily work, and after a day or two (with a couple of restarts in this period) it began working again. And till now, I haven't encountered the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the path for sdk/build-tools in the terminal

```
export PATH="Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/...":$PATH
```

after that restart the emulator and try

```
npm run android
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix I have found that works for me is to:

1. Close the emulated device so you have nothing listed when running `adb devices`
2. Run `react-native run-android` so the build fails correctly with a `No connected devices!` error
3. Restart the emulator and run `react-native run-android` again

Unfortunately I still have to run this after every restart, would love to get to the root cause and fix it once and for all!

Answer (score 0):

If you had hit the following error while installing watchman, you will most likely hit the issue mentioned in this discussion

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
```

If this is the case, check what the watchman window shows.  If it is something like this:

```
 Watchman: watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2018-08-24T17:37:44,142: [0x7fffab20d380] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/macbookpro-state: No such file or directory
```

Do

```
> brew uninstall watchman
> cd /usr/local/var/
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) var
> brew update
> brew install watchman
```

Kill/close the emulator device and run the command

```
> react-native run-android
```

You should see the action fail with message like

```
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Now, rerun the command to see the compilation successful and the app opening up in the emulator

```
> react-native run-android
```